# Request: Splice text/string every nth char, but ignoring a specific char?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**It's a little confusing but if you look at the example below you get it!**

I have a special "Console.Write" method that takes a string, for example "§cHello %mThere!" and when printing to the Console, this method ignores the §c and %m (it changes the color of the Console).

Now, I have another method to print text by aligning it, by breaking the string into an array of strings every nth char. That means, if I pass a string of 100 chars and a LineLength of 10, it will break my string into an array of 10 strings with 10 chars each, then my Write method will print each one in a new line.

The problem is, when I split the text every nth char, it count the '§' and 'c' chars, and when I print it (the method for printing will remove those two), so the output is off by two chars.

**So**... I need a method that:

1. Splits a string into an array of strings every nth character.
2. However, it must not count '§' and the following char, or '%' and the next char as characters in that math.
3. The output must have those extra chars in the string array.

**Example:**

```
string Text = "§cOnce upon a time there was a §R%mnice girl named Cinderella. She was very poor and her father passed way."

int LineLength = 6;

return string[] Output = {
"§conce u" //[o n c e space u], thats 6 chars ignoring the first two.
"pon a "   //[p o n space a space], thats 6 chars.
"time t"   // etc
//etc
}
```

If someone help me write this, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Please include at least 17 sample inputs and the expected results for each of those 17.

Comment: Although not every question needs an attempt, It is always beneficial to do so. It may show just a simple mistake, or extra information not provided in the actual question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying this seems about right.

```
public static string[] ConsoleChunk(string input, int length){
    List<string> Output = new List<string>();
    int k = 0;
    string currentString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++){
      if(k == 6){
        Output.Add(currentString);
        currentString = input[i].ToString();
        k = 1;  
      }
      else if(input[i] == '§' || input[i] == '%'){
        currentString += input[i];
        currentString += input[++i];
      }
      else{
        k++;
        currentString += input[i];
      }
      
    }
    Output.Add(currentString);
    return Output.ToArray();
  }
```

Input

```
string test = "§cOnce upon a time there was a §R%mnice girl named Cinderella. She was very poor and her father passed way.";
```

Output

```
§cOnce u
pon a 
time t
here w
as a §R%mn
ice gi
rl nam
ed Cin
derell
a. She
 was v
ery po
or and
 her f
ather 
passed
 way.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FunkyChunk(string source, int size)
{
   var index = 0;
   while (index < source.Length)
   {
      var sb = new StringBuilder(size*2);
      for (int count = 0; count<size && index < source.Length; index++)
      {
         sb.Append(source[index]);
         if (source[index] != '§' && source[index] != '%')
            count++;
      }

      yield return sb.ToString();
   }
}
```

<sub>***Note** : This is O(n) and used `StringBuilder` for less allocations even though there would be more succinct solutions. Using a fixed buffer and another index would likely be better*</sub>

**Usage**

```
var input = "012345§678901234567%890123%4567890123456§§789012§345678901234";

foreach (var result in FunkyChunk(input,10))
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
012345§6789
01234567%89
0123%456789
0123456§§789
012§3456789
01234
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQIrww)